# How to join nodes and relationships in Neo4j to make sentences?

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, cypher

I am currently doing a research project and I've built 2 ontologies of 2 domains using Neo4j graph database. Now there's a requirement for me to construct sentences using the nodes and relationships separately for the two domains for a string matching purpose. For example, if the nodes and relationship are as follows:

```
(n:Person{name:'John'})-[r:knows]->(m:Person{name:'Smith'})
```

I want to get the sentence "John knows Smith". Also, another important thing is in the ontologies there are different types of relationships. So I want to get the sentences without worrying about the relationship types. For example, if we take the above example I should be able to get the result without having to use the relationship type "knows" anywhere, simply by using a generic way.

I have built the ontologies on the same sandbox by giving "Finance" and "Politics" as node labels to differentiate them. I've given a property to each node as "name" and it states the word of the domain. For example, if there's a word in the financial domain as 'profit' the create query would be like CREATE(n:Finance{name:'profit'}). I want to get the name of the nodes and make the sentence.

Is there a suitable Neo4j query to do so or is there a way to accomplish this by using a Spring Boot backend API. I've already constructed a Spring Boot API to do some basic functionalities like adding nodes and relationships. What I'm asking is, is there a direct query to build sentences from nodes and relationships or is there a way to do so by using Java Spring Boot? But it would be great if anyone can suggest a neo4j query to accomplish this.

Comment: Please do not ask in the comments for urgent assistance; all questions are of equal priority here. Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I if understand your question, you can use [type()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-type) function.

```
match (a)-[r]->(b)
return a.name + " " + type(r) + " " + b.name
```

Comment: Bruno Peres,
It's so close for my expectation. Thanks for that. But I need a little modification. I have built the ontologies on the same sandbox by giving "Finance" and "Politics" as node labels to differentiate them. I've given a property to each node as "name" and it states the word of the domain. For example if there's a word in financial domain as profit the create query would be like CREATE(n:Finance{name:'profit'}). I want to get the name of the nodes and make the sentence. Is there a way to do so. Anyway your answer has brought me hope because I tried for a lot of time.Thanks.

Comment: Bruno Peres, I updated my question again. I hope it will clear things a little more. Can anyone suggest a suitable way?

Comment: Hi @HareendraChamaraPhilips I don't know if I understand, but you can try changing the `labels()` call by `a.name` and `b.name`, like `match (a)-[r]->(b)
return a.name + " " + type(r) + " " + b.name`. Please, let me know if it works.

Comment: @HareendraChamaraPhilips you are welcome. I will update my answer. Can you accept it as the right answer by clicking on the check-mark? Thanks.